# Me puse [adj] vs Me puso [adj]

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

To say `I became [adj]`, I can say:

> Me puse pensativo/enfermo/nervioso

However, I've also heard `me puso [adj]` in the same context.

> Me puso pensativo/enfermo/nervioso

What's the difference between the two **meaning-wise**? Is this a passive voice, this is it? "Something made me...."?

update:

I'm not taking about "él, ella" for "puso". But "it".

Comment: Me puse nervioso: I got nervous.  Me puso nervioso: She/He made me nervous [She/He got me all in a tizzy.]  In the second example somebody else gets blamed for my nervousness -- for example, maybe the somebody is talking very fast, and saying things that undermine my self-confidence.

Comment: @aparente001 `Me puso nervioso` --> it made me nervous

Comment: yes, good point, both are possible, depending on the context.  A situation can make somebody nervous, indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got it:

> Me puse enfermo.

You are not telling what made you to become ill, maybe it is not important or it's unknown. Besides, this sentence usually has a literal meaning

> (Algo) me puso enfermo.

Here the emphasis is in the subject, there is a known cause. Maybe the food poisoned me, or someone passed me their illness, so I am blaming it on something or someone. This sentence also can be used in a metaphorical way, similar to "I'm sick of / I've had enough of ..."

Answer (score 9):

**The difference is the subject of the sentence.** Check that different endings correspond to different subjects. If you conjugate the verb *poner* in past simple, you have

> yo puse
>   tú pusiste
>   él/ella/esto/eso puso
>   ...

So `me puse` is actually `yo me puse`, which would literally translate as "I put myself", and it actually means "I became".

On the other hand, `me puso` is (3rd person) actually `él me puso` or `ella me puso` or 'esto/eso/aquello' **(anything 3rd person)**, which is "(s)he put me", or "(s)he made me become" using any third person  **he/she/it/this/that**.

In other words, the difference is **puse** is first person and **puso** is third person.

Comment: you didn't understand my question

Comment: `me puso` --> this can be also "it made me...." which is the same as "I got ...". and hence  my question

Comment: True, we usually think of 3rd person as he or she, but it can also be "it". "That made me..." instead of "He made me"

Comment: Perhaps some examples will help you realize this is the right answer. = "I got sick"="**Me puse** enfermo" , "Some virus made me sick"= "algún virus **me puso** enfermo", "I got/became sick from a virus"= "**Me puse** enfermo por un virus", "I became nervous"="**Me puse** nervioso", "That horror movie made me nervous" =  "La película de terror **me puso** nervioso" or "**Me puse** nervioso por la película de terror".

Comment: Then my question remains -- what's the difference?

Comment: @DGaleano I know. Re-read my question

Comment: I've read it. If this is not the answer then we should close it as "unclear what you are asking" 

Comment: He choose the other as the answer. Amazing!!!. Anyway both answers say the same and that's why I +1 the other answer also.